# Discrepancy CNS006 and CryptoNote whitepaper one-time key generation

Tags: cryptonote, cryptography, stealth-address

CryptoNote 2.0 uses P=Hs(rA)G + B for the generation of a one-time key.

[CNS006](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns006.txt) seems te change this to P=Hs(rA||n)+B, where n is the transaction index (encoded as varint).

Why is there this additional concatenation; is this to conceal transactions to the same address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CNS006 is correct. In the past outputs had to be split into denominations and without concatenations that'd generate multiple identical outputs (of different amounts) to the same wallet, effectively burning all but 1. With the concatenation, it's guaranteed that outputs will be unique, even if going to the same address.

Comment: So it is to "conceal" transactions to the same address before RingCT, I see. Thanks!